# gdal_calc.py for command line (windows) using Anaconda 3.3.0

Tags: python, gdal

I'm using gdal_calc.py to do some raster operations.

1- i activate anaconda with this command :
C:/Users/Dell/miniconda3/Scripts/activate.bat

2-then i activate my envs :
C:\Users\Dell>conda activate tutorial

3-then i execute this :
gdal_calc.py --overwrite -A C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/DATA/RasterTEST.tif --outfile C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/DATA/result.tif --calc="A>10"

the probelem is that i don't have anything as output
when i run the last command i file is open :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try prefixing your command with `python`.  The default "open with" behavior for .py files is probably to display them in your editor.

Comment: ya that exactly what i tired and it's working , thank you for you answer